# Pycharm: Attribute Error

Tags: python, import, module, pycharm, attributeerror

I have a project in Pycharm:

ProjectName (set as SourceRoot)

```
|_package1
  |- __init__.py
   -  package1.py
|_package2
  |- __init__.py
   - secondpythonfile.py
```

The firstpythonfile.py contains the function placementfunction().

From secondpythonfile.py I want to call that function.

IN firstpythonfile.py:

```
  from package2 import secondpythonfile
```

and

```
  secondpythonfile.placementfunction()
```

But Pycharm gives m the following error:

```
    AttributeError: module 'package2.secondpythonfile ' has no attribute 'placementfunction'
```

There appear to be a ton of Attribute Errors associated with PyCharm, but I am wondering whether there is some straight forward advice out there or someone who has dealt with this issue before?

Comment: Your error message does not match the command and structure you gave.

Comment: Woops sorry. Will amend. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Pycharm didn't like the fact that my package name 'package1' was the same as the file name package1.py inside. As soon as I changed it it worked.